# Professor gave full credit for incompleteness

Tags: grading

My professor gives full credit for every single assignment I have turned in for the past 9 weeks (except for a paper we had for which he gave me individual feedback on my writing). I did everything I was supposed to do and fully completed each assignment until the most recent one.

I recently turned in an assignment on time last night, but I didn’t have it fully completed (1 question incomplete). Sure enough he gave me 100% of the points, but I’m not sure I deserve it, or if he even looks at some of the assignments.

Should I do or say anything? I don’t know if he thinks I deserve the grade he gave me or not, or if he just somehow didn’t notice one of the questions incomplete.

**Added Clarification:** All the grades (except for the 3 papers) seem to all be copy/pasted as they’re not specific to my writing (this is in an American Literature class). The comment for my incomplete assignment is along the lines of so and so made a change in American Literature, they shifted the focus towards nature. I can give the exact words of the comment, but I don’t think it’s necessary, the point is: the comment isn’t specific to my answers, leading me to suspect he may not actually read it (I can’t be 100% though).
-I should also add that I wrote way more than the minimum word count for some of the questions, but I still don’t necessarily feel like I deserve the grade. I was literally up at 11:59pm and turned it in *last second*

Comment: Is the way he gives grades transparent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems an odd policy and, as a colleague, I'd be interested to know why he does this. But I wouldn't condemn it without more information.

However, if it is clear that he actually reads your work and comments on it when necessary to avoid having you develop misconceptions, then it might be fine. It is even possible that what you do provide makes it clear to him that you understand what needs to be understood. But it is hard to say.

If you got full marks by not trying at all, of course, then the standards are too low, but it seems to be a "carrot but no stick" approach.

But the fact that you are asking here seems to imply that you are conscientious, at least and if you get feedback when needed you will probably be fine. But, I think that asking about the teaching philosophy behind it is also fine.

It is also possible, I suppose, that he has a reading difficulty, the same as some students do, or is so occupied with things like research (or family) that he fails to notice things. That wouldn't be so fine.

But, as I've stressed in other answers here, the essence of learning is reinforcement and feedback. If you are getting that, then all should be well. Some people don't need to be *graders* in order to be good *teachers*. I wish there were more, to be honest.